# Difference between statistics from database and Admin-Frontend

Tags: python, mysql, openx

I am product-manager for a distributed OpenX-Setup (4 Delivery-, 1 DB-Server). I am trying to write my own python scripts, that generate reports.

When I connect to the database and query for the data from one day, the results differ slightly from the statistics-view from the adminfrontend. The revenue i.e. differs by .5%.

The SQL-Query:

```
SELECT data_summary_ad_hourly_id, date_time, ad_id, zone_id, requests, impressions, 
       clicks, conversions, total_revenue
FROM ox_data_summary_ad_hourly
WHERE date(date_time) = '2012-11-21'
ORDER BY ad_id, zone_id DESC
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: What query is run by the admin front end?

Comment: That is my problem, as I have really no clue, as I cannot read the php-source. So I hoped for someone, who has knowledge of the php-source to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, the numbers between the OpenX-admin-frontend and the db-query are slightly off:

The **timezone is different** between the OpenX-Server and the computer I use to query the db. So this one hour (as it is in my case) lets the numbers slightly differ.

So either you change the timezone of your OpenX-Installation, or you account for this in your db-query.

Hope I could help.